# C++ dynamic library and std::unique_ptr breaking stack with debug symbols on

Tags: c++, dll, stl, crash, stack

I made a repository with a simplified version of the problem I encountered with my project:
https://github.com/michalPietraszko/Test

*PS. I'm not that familiar with premake so you need to build the project twice for it to work*

In short, when I build the project with sybmols on I get a debug assertion failure:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: ...Tst\Test\Client..\bin\Debug-windows-x86_64\Client\Client.exe
> File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp
> Line: 996
>
> Expression: __acrt_first_block == header

It runs fine with sybmols off.

**I have 2 questions:**

- Is my approach even correct?
- Why is it failing only with debug configuration?

Thank you in advance!!!!!

Library code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    #define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace lib
{
    class API Event
    {
    public:
        std::string toString() const { std::stringstream ss; ss<<"example str"; return ss.str(); }
        const char* getName() const { return "example char"; }
    };

    class API Layer
    {
    public:
        virtual void onEvent(Event&) {}
    };

    class API Application
    {
    public:
        Application() = default;
        Application(const Application&) = delete;
        Application(Application&&) = default;
        Application& operator=(Application&&) = default;
        Application& operator=(const Application&) = delete;
        ~Application() = default;
               
        template<typename T>
        void pushLayer()
        {
            vec.push_back(std::make_unique<T>());
        }

        void run()
        {   
            bool doneOnce{ false };
            while (true) 
            {
                if (!doneOnce) 
                {
                    Event e{};
                    (*vec.begin())->onEvent(e);
                    doneOnce = true;
                }
            }
        }

        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Layer>> vec;
    };

    Application* createApplication(); // define in client
}// namespace
```

Client code:

```
#include <Main.hpp>

class Example : public lib::Layer
{
public:
    void onEvent(lib::Event& e) override
    {
        std::cout << "On Event" << std::endl;

        std::string s = e.toString(); // crashes application upon exiting the scope
        std::cout << s << std::endl; 

        //std::cout << e.toString() << std::endl; // crashes after this line

        //e.getName(); // returns const char*, works fine
        
        std::cout << "I did run ok" << std::endl;
    }
};

extern lib::Application* lib::createApplication();

class Client : public lib::Application
{
public:
    Client() { pushLayer<Example>(); }
};

lib::Application* lib::createApplication()
{
    return new Client();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto app = lib::createApplication();
    app->run();
    delete app;
}
```

Premake file:

```
--pramake.lua

workspace "Test"
    architecture "x64"

    configurations
    {
        "Debug",
        "Release"
    }

outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}"

--include "Luna/vendor/GLFW"
startproject "Client"

project "DynLib"
    location "DynLib"
    kind "SharedLib"
    language "C++"

    targetdir("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

--    pchheader "lnpch.h"
--    pchsource "Luna/src/lnpch.cpp"

    files
    {
        "%{prj.name}/**.hpp",
        "%{prj.name}/**.cpp"
    }

    includedirs
    {
        "%{prj.name}/"
    } 

    filter "system:windows"
        cppdialect "C++17"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"

        defines
        {
            "BUILD_DLL"
        }

        postbuildcommands
        {
            ("{COPY} %{cfg.buildtarget.relpath} ../bin/" .. outputdir .. "/Client")
        }
    
    filter "configurations:Debug"
        symbols "On"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        symbols "Off"

project "Client"
    location "Client"
    kind "ConsoleApp"    
    language "C++"

    targetdir("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files
    {
        "%{prj.name}/**.hpp",
        "%{prj.name}/**.cpp"
    }

    includedirs
    {
        "DynLib/"
    }

    links
    {
        "DynLib"
    }

    filter "system:windows"
        cppdialect "C++17"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"

        defines
        {
            "LN_PLATFORM_WINDOWS",
        }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        symbols "On"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        symbols "Off"
```

Comment: You are asking why you only get the debug-only error in debug and not release? Probably because it is not turned on in release.

Comment: The good news is that as of last month MSVC now supports Address Sanitizer. This looks like a heap corruption bug (from the error messages), so turn that on and see what happens.

Comment: I'm asking why I'm getting the error in the first place and why it is a problem (crashes program) on debug. I can see that it is not on release because it's not turned on but *why* it is a problem on debug in the first place. I'm sorry but your answer is not adding anything new to the problem.

Comment: `Application::run()` will never return.  Is that intended ?

Comment: @walnut sorry why would you look into the first commit instead? It's probably not even compling

Comment: @MichałP. I have deleted my answer, but I suggest you add the virtual destructors to the example and remove the infinite loop from it, so that others aren't also distracted by it, if neither of these issues is relevant to what you want to ask about. (As always verify that the problem is still present after the changes.)

Comment: You're correct it's probably just a distraction, I tried it without the loop and with virtual destructors and the effect was the same. No reason to keep it